# Jquery animate image invert

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, colors

Im trying to animate the inversion of the colors of an image. I can invert the image like this:

```
 $("#menuButtonImage").css({filter : "invert(100%)"});
```

This is my animation code, which puts out no error in the console but does not animate:

```
$("#menuButtonImage").animate({filter : "invert(100%)"}, "slow");
```

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I guess jQuery doesn't know what to do with the filter string. Try using css transitions and toggle classes

Comment: yep, use css `transition: all 1.0s ease;` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working HTML:

```
<div id='menuButton'>
    <button id='menuButtonButton'>
        <img src="./images/MenuIcon.png" id='menuButtonImage'>
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menuButton button img {
   transition: all 1.0s ease;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#menuButtonButton").click(function() {
     $("#menuButtonImage").css({filter : "invert(100%)"});
});
```